# Binary tree iterative traversal picks up only one branch

Tags: c#, binary-tree

learning how to use those things like binary trees. Have one issue ...

```cs
    public class ProgramTest
    {

        public class TestBinaryTree : Program.BinaryTree
        {
            public TestBinaryTree(int value) : base(value)
            {
            }

            public TestBinaryTree Insert(List<int> values)
            {
                return Insert(values, 0);
            }

            public TestBinaryTree Insert(List<int> values, int i)
            {
                if (i >= values.Count) return null;

                List<TestBinaryTree> queue = new List<TestBinaryTree>();
                queue.Add(this);
                while (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    TestBinaryTree current = queue[0];
                    queue.RemoveAt(0);
                    if (current.left == null)
                    {
                        current.left = new TestBinaryTree(values[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    queue.Add((TestBinaryTree)current.left);
                    if (current.right == null)
                    {
                        current.right = new TestBinaryTree(values[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    queue.Add((TestBinaryTree)current.right);
                }
                Insert(values, i + 1);
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public class BinaryTree
        {
            public int value;
            public BinaryTree left;
            public BinaryTree right;

            public BinaryTree(int value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                this.left = null;
                this.right = null;
            }
        }

        public static List<int> BranchSums(BinaryTree root)
        {

            Stack<BinaryTree> myStack = new Stack<BinaryTree>();
            myStack.Push(root);
            while(myStack.Count > 0)
            {
                var current = myStack.Pop();

                Console.WriteLine(current.value);
                if(current.right != null) myStack.Push(current.left);
                if (current.left != null) myStack.Push(current.left);
            }
            return new List<int>();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestBinaryTree tree = new TestBinaryTree(1).Insert(new List<int>(){2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10});
            BranchSums(tree);
        }
    }
```

To reproduce it, just run Main().
Binary tree inside looks like:

```
           1
        /     \
       2       3
     /   \    /  \
    4     5  6    7
  /   \  /
 8    9 10
```

```
1
2
4
8
8
4
8
8
2
4
8
8
4
8
8
```

And it seems, that it only prints out only first left branch: `1 2 4 8` For some reason it is not going further :(
In my case, it should go through all the branches, not the just one

Comment: Could it be because you're only pushing the left? `if(current.right != null) myStack.Push(current.left); if (current.left != null) myStack.Push(current.left);`

Comment: Thanks, that could be the one issue, but it didn't fix it ... Tried isolating if statements, but result is the same ```    Console.WriteLine(current.value);
    if(current.right != null)
                {
     myStack.Push(current.left);
                }
    if (current.left != null)
    {
     myStack.Push(current.left);
    }
```

Comment: Ohh sorry, i understood you :D Yea, it helped, Replaced one current.left with current.right, and it works. Thanks